# Refactoring package name breaks entire app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, refactoring, android-manifest

I am trying to refactor my package using Eclipse

```
org.sheehan.activity
```

to

```
org.sheehan.stocks.activity
```

For some reason my project just blows up when I do this and R doesn't get regenerated. How can I refactor properly?

**UPDATE**:
I updated my Android Manifest to reflect the change. R still doesn't get regenerated. Even after a clean. The compiler is complaining about org.sheehan.activity.R

Comment: Your question led me to "break" Eclipse in so many ways...your answer didn't work until I closed Eclipse and tried again.  Check out my answer for a good laugh!  I think you really helped a lot of people.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I resolved by:

```
Android Tools > Rename Package Application
```

Comment: The re-factor didn't work 100%, so I had to do that after fixing my Android manifest. There were quotation marks missing.

Comment: For super beginners, make sure to highlight your project in the Project Explorer, right click, and you'll see Android Tools near the bottom

Answer (score 2):

If you renamed properly, all your references across your project should have gotten updated. After doing this, clean your project by going to Project > Clean. This should fix it.

Comment: I tried Project > Clean, no luck. R is still pointing to the old package

Comment: You can also delete the R file and force it to regenerate that way?

Comment: Thats the problem, the gen folder doesn't have an R anymore. When I open/close/clean the project nothing happens.

Comment: What if you make a change and save? Is your workspace setting set to build/refresh automatically? (Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace)

Answer (score 1):

Fixing missing reference to `R` in eclipse:

1. Refactor -> Rename`
2. Build -> Clean
3. Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties

Comment: check if you have any error on any xml files may be this can help you

Answer (score 1):

select the base package of your project in the eclipse package explorer, press F2 (Rename), in the rename dialog: SELECT ALL the checkboxes.:
[image]

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

The package name doesn't update in the XML files. Specifically your manifest which needs to know the base package.

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced imports and refactors, literally closing the Eclipse IDE can refresh a cache that causes random errors like "End position lies outside document range" or the "what once worked now doesn't hair puller outter errors."

Signs you should close Eclipse when trying to rename things are:

1. When you import a project, do some refactoring (like trying to change the package name), then delete the project and try again, you will see immediate R.java errors when you didn't before
2. When you are importing projects that have manually generated R.java files that have custom imports like "com.ns.proj.R" and don't see the name update in Preview
3. The box that asks if you want to "Rename subpackages" is checked unexpectedly
4. the code in the "Preview>>" looks as if it's been complied before instead of black and white code with the proper names replaced
5. you get XML errors in the manifest activity name like this

> android:name="com.ns.proj.CustomCocom.ns.proj.CustomControlse="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"

when it should be

> android:name="com.ns.proj.CustomControls"
>    android:style="Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"

There are too many to name obviously, however this is as important as "keep your eye on the ball" in sports.  Something that is so easy to forget, yet  things like these apply to other software programs like Dreamweaver (e.g. when you use the Dreamweaver "Put" option instead of FTP dragging with FileZilla and you notice your domain isn't updating your changes online).  I called Adobe when I first started as a developer 8 years ago because I knew I wasn't doing anything wrong.  They said sometimes the generated files to perform the action get corrupted...in other words, IDE's have bugs too!

In general, close the IDE before you off yourself...it could save your life!

Answer (score 0):

Right click in your Project, go to

```
Android Tools > Rename Package Application
```

Sometimes if  `Project > Clean` doesn´t work, so Delete `/gen` and `/bin` folders of your project.