# Android: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I reinstalled the ADT Bundle, because I had some problems after updating eclipse.

Now I get the following exception, when I want to test my app:

```
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{foo.bar/foo.bar.TabsFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.TabsFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/foo.bar-2.apk]
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1670)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.TabsFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/foo.bar-2.apk]
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
06-05 10:33:35.770: E/AndroidRuntime(17751):    ... 11 more
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="foo.bar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="foo.bar.ui.tabs.TabsFragmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="foo.bar.ui.activities.EditActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="foo.bar.ui.tabs.TabsFragmentActivity" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="foo.bar.ui.activities.LocationActivity"
            android:label="Select a location"
            android:parentActivityName="foo.bar.ui.tabs.TabsFragmentActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="foo.bar.ui.activities.DeleteLocationsActivity"
            android:label="Delete locations"
            android:parentActivityName="foo.bar.ui.activities.LocationActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="foo.bar.ui.activities.ShowLocationActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="foo.bar.ui.activities.LocationActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="foo.bar.ui.activities.ShowSnapshotActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="foo.bar.ui.activities.ShowLocationActivity" >
        </activity>
        <service 
            android:name="foo.bar.service.SnapshotService" >
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think it has done something to do with the packaging, ie. it looks at the wrong place for the activity, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried cleaning the project and using only ".activityname" in the manifest, which both didn't work.

EDIT: I got it to work now by moving the TabsFragmentActivity to the standard package and then back to ui.tabs.

Not sure why this worked though.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: could you post the activity code and project package structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.TabsFragmentActivity
```

And from your manifest:

```
android:name="foo.bar.ui.tabs.TabsFragmentActivity"
```

So, my suggestion is to:

- move TabsFragmentActivity to foo.bar.ui.tabs
- or change android:name="foo.bar.ui.tabs.TabsFragmentActivity" to android:name="foo.bar.TabsFragmentActivity"

> **Note:**

If you recently updated your ADT plugin then:

In Eclipse right click on project -> properties -> java Build Path -> Order & Export and check Android Private Libraries(Android Support Library previously) for your project and also in all other library projects you are using. Clean and Build again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: TabsFragmentActivity already is in the package foo.bar.ui.tabs

Comment: It occurs as soon as I start the app. I don't think there is any code involved, because it worked before the update

Comment: Check my Updated answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you have rename package name from Refactor.At that time you asked for some options like

- Update References
- rename subpackages
- update textual occurence.....
- updatefully Java textfiles....

So you have to make changes as you want from here.,,
Now do one thing,again make your Package name as Previous if you remember it,and thn again Refactor it.. MAy be this will help.

Or Use Android Tools--->Rename Application PAckage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500042/refactoring-package-name-breaks-entire-app   Check this...

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error only when I import projects that I cloned from Github, and my solution is like this:

1. Right-click your project in Eclipse, select `Properties`
2. Select `Java Build Path` in the left then select `Order and Export` tab
3. Tick

   - `Android 4.2(or any other version that you are using)`
   - `Android Private Libraries`
   - `Android Dependencies`
4. Press `OK` then do a project clean

These names above may vary, this works every time when I got the `ClassNotFound` exception.